# Javascript TCP connection to server

Tags: javascript, sockets, tcp

I have created server daemon, that produces some data, like messages and so. But, what im interested in - client monitoring. For example i have web page, and i need to establish persistent Tcp connection to server and show all incoming data into textbox. I know it can be done with flash, but im searching for JS implementation.

Is it possible and what`s the best practices ?

Comment: You are not going to get tcp/sockets with JavaScript. You are stuck with http.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're asking for is known as [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)).  Plenty of server software and client libraries exist - see the linked Wikipedia page.

Comment: so, for example Facebook chat client uses same technology ?

Comment: Not necessarily - a web chat can be created using a simple polling technique, where JavaScript simply makes a request to the server for new messages every few seconds. Granted, not a great approach, but it works.

Comment: Yeah, i found this approach matching my needs after analyzing facebook`s chat system. It`s kinda private messages, but accessible on fly.

Answer (score 4):

[WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets) is designed to solve this problem.